# Woocommerce emails template update and grab a custom field from order_details

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Getting data from the order number variable does not work. If you write the order number immediately, everything works.
Why does it work like that?

```
add_action( "woocommerce_email_after_order_table", "custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table", 10, 1);

function custom_woocommerce_email_after_order_table( $order ) {

   echo  "ORDER - ".$order->id;
    echo '<p><strong>Custom field (id on other field) :</strong>'. get_post_meta( 359, "bought_through_ads", true ) .'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Custom field (id on other field):</strong>'. get_post_meta(  $order->id, "bought_through_ads", true ) .'</p>';

    get_customer_log_html(359);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Since WooCommerce 3 (2017) use `$order->get_id()` not `$order->id` OR use  `$order->get_meta()`

Comment: @7uc1f3r I showed in the screenshot and in the code. that $order->id; output. But it is not possible to get the value through the order ID variable.